# Given a string S, remove consecutive duplicates from it recursively using python

Tags: python, string, recursion, duplicates

i am adding str[1] that is causing one repeated element to be left but if donot do that string does not get printed. any solutions

```
def removeCD(str):
    l  = len(str)
    if l == 0 or l == 1:
        return str
    if(str[0]==str[1]):
        return str[1] + removeCD(str[2:])
    else:
        return  str[0] + removeCD(str[1:])

string = input().strip()
print(removeCD(string))
```

Comment: Could you give some samples of expected input and output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the case analysis we need to perform -

1. If string length is *less than two* (base case), there is nothing to compare, simply return the string
2. Otherwise (by induction) the string is *at least two* characters long. If the first matches the second, drop the first letter and return the recursive result
3. Otherwise (by induction) the string is at least two characters long and the first two characters *do not match*. Return the first char combined with the recursive result.

This encodes to a python program in a straightforward way -

```py
def remove_adjacent_dupes (s = ""):
  if len(s) < 2:
    return s
  elif s[0] == s[1]:
    return remove_adjacent_dupes(s[1:])
  else:
    return s[0] + remove_adjacent_dupes(s[1:])

print(remove_adjacent_dupes("bookkeeper"))
# bokeper
```

Answer (score 1):

When characters are equal, you again adding duplicate character. This should work:

```
def removeCD(str):
    l  = len(str)
    if l == 0 or l == 1:
        return str
    if(str[0]==str[1]):
        return removeCD(str[1:])
    else:
        return  str[0] + removeCD(str[1:])

string = input().strip()
print(removeCD(string))
```

Comment: Alternative: You can even use `itertools.groupby` here. `''.join(k for k,g in groupby('aaaabbbcccc'))--->'abc`. Not complaining about the answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

When the characters are equal, you should be recursing on everything but the first character:

```
if(str[0]==str[1]):
    return removeCD(str[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def remove(string):
    l = len(string)
    if l==0 or l==1:
        return string
    if string[0] == string[1]:
        s = remove(string[1:])
        return s
    else:
        s = remove(string[1:])
        return string[0]+s

string = input().strip()
print(remove(string))
```

Comment: You should also add a brief explanation to your answer.

Comment: I agree, some explanation would be useful.